# complexity of polygon-construction

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to proof that the complexity of the problem to construct a *simple polygon* out of a given set of points (2D) is at least *O(n*logn)*, i.e. every correct algorithm takes at least O(n*logn) steps to solve this problem in the worst case.
Is it possible to reduce this problem to a sorting problem somehow or how can this be shown?

Comment: No, i don't mean the convex hull. A definition of a simple polygon is given e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the baseline algorithm:

[image]

- Find two points with lowest and highest x-value: O(n)
- Divide other points in two sets lying above and below the baseline (line joining these points): O(n)
- Sort upper set in "ascending y/ascending x"-order: O(n*logn)
- Sort lower set in "descending y/desending x"-order: O(n*logn)
- Join upper set in order, join lower set in order: O(n)

Comment: Does this somehow establish that you can't do it any faster than O(n*log n)?

Comment: Yes, as n.m points out: If your n points all lie on a unit circle, then their polar coordinates form an order function. If you had a construction algorithm with complexity C(n), this would give you the unique simple polygon running around the circle. Its points are ordered by their polar coordinate, modulo 2*Pi. With a shift of O(n) you get an absolute polar order, thus with a complexity of C(n)+O(n).

Comment: So, if a had a "convex set of points" it takes O(n*logn) the put them in a correct order, thus it cannot be done faster in general, is that the point?

Comment: furthermore, what happens, if there are points ON the baseline, then your algorithm does not work, does it?

Comment: It still works, try dragging the inner vertices in the picture to the baseline and see.

Comment: @Hans Meierwurst Values in the interval [0, 2*Pi] map 1-to-1 to points on the unit circle. If those values cannot be ordered faster than O(n*logn), so can't the points on the circle. Proving that O(n*logn) is fastes in general.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to prove it by a way of comparing it to the sorting problem, but you must reduce it the other way around. That is, reduce the sorting problem to the polygon-construction problem in O(n) time.